# Get all file names from a Github repo through the Github API

Tags: github, github-api

Is it possible to get all the file names from repository using the GitHub API?

I'm currently trying to tinker this using [PyGithub](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub), but I'm totally ok with manually doing the request as long as it works.

My algorithm so far is:

1. Get the user repo names
2. Get the user repo that matches a certain description
3. ??? get repo file names?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This will have to be relative to a particular commit, as some files may be present in some commits and absent in others, so before you can look at files you'll need to use something like [List commits on a repository](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository):

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/commits
```

If you're just interested in the latest commit on a branch you can set the `sha` parameter to the branch name:

> `sha` `string` SHA or branch to start listing commits from.

Once you have a commit hash, you can [inspect that commit](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/#get-a-commit)

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/git/commits/:sha
```

which should return something like this (truncated from GitHub's documentation):

```
{
  "sha": "...",
  "...",
  "tree": {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/trees/691272480426f78a0138979dd3ce63b77f706feb",
    "sha": "691272480426f78a0138979dd3ce63b77f706feb"
  },
  "...": "..."
}
```

Look at the hash of its *tree*, which is essentially its directory contents. In this case, `691272480426f78a0138979dd3ce63b77f706feb`. Now we can finally [request the contents of that tree](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/#get-a-tree):

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/git/trees/:sha
```

The output from GitHub's example is

```
{
  "sha": "9fb037999f264ba9a7fc6274d15fa3ae2ab98312",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/trees/9fb037999f264ba9a7fc6274d15fa3ae2ab98312",
  "tree": [
    {
      "path": "file.rb",
      "mode": "100644",
      "type": "blob",
      "size": 30,
      "sha": "44b4fc6d56897b048c772eb4087f854f46256132",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/blobs/44b4fc6d56897b048c772eb4087f854f46256132"
    },
    {
      "path": "subdir",
      "mode": "040000",
      "type": "tree",
      "sha": "f484d249c660418515fb01c2b9662073663c242e",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/blobs/f484d249c660418515fb01c2b9662073663c242e"
    },
    {
      "path": "exec_file",
      "mode": "100755",
      "type": "blob",
      "size": 75,
      "sha": "45b983be36b73c0788dc9cbcb76cbb80fc7bb057",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/git/blobs/45b983be36b73c0788dc9cbcb76cbb80fc7bb057"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, we have some *blobs*, which correspond to files, and some additional trees, which correspond to subdirectories. You may want to [do this recursively](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/#get-a-tree-recursively).

Comment: The [Repository Contents API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents) may also be worth a look. It provides a familiar directory-style navigation structure, exposing a tree of directories and files.

Comment: `:sha` can be label, as `master`

Comment: Seems to have trouble listing the directory with over 100,000 files; try to download the whole repo and process locally would be an option: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51529060/python-requests-get-all-files-from-a-git-folder)

Answer (score 55):

You can use [Github git trees](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/)

`https://api.github.com/repos/[USER]/[REPO]/git/trees/[BRANCH]?recursive=1`

**Repo**

https://github.com/deeja/bing-maps-loader

**Api Call**

https://api.github.com/repos/deeja/bing-maps-loader/git/trees/master?recursive=1

*which returns*

```
{
sha: "55382e87889ccb4c173bc99a42cc738358fc253a",
url: "https://api.github.com/repos/deeja/bing-maps-loader/git/trees/55382e87889ccb4c173bc99a42cc738358fc253a",
tree: [
{
path: "README.md",
mode: "100644",
type: "blob",
sha: "41ceefc1262bb80a25529342ee3ec2ec7add7063",
size: 3196,
url: "https://api.github.com/repos/deeja/bing-maps-loader/git/blobs/41ceefc1262bb80a25529342ee3ec2ec7add7063"
},
{
path: "index.js",
mode: "100644",
type: "blob",
sha: "a81c94f70d1ca2a0df02bae36eb2aa920c7fb20e",
size: 1581,
url: "https://api.github.com/repos/deeja/bing-maps-loader/git/blobs/a81c94f70d1ca2a0df02bae36eb2aa920c7fb20e"
},
{
path: "package.json",
mode: "100644",
type: "blob",
sha: "45f24dcb7a457b14fede4cb907e957600882b340",
size: 595,
url: "https://api.github.com/repos/deeja/bing-maps-loader/git/blobs/45f24dcb7a457b14fede4cb907e957600882b340"
}
],
truncated: false
}
```

Answer (score 22):

Much eaiser now with the graphql api, you can get it all in a single query

first you get your repo:

```
query {
  repository(name: "MyRepo" owner: "mylogin"){

  }
}
```

then you get its defaultBranchRef to make life easy

```
    defaultBranchRef{

    }
```

Now all a branch ref really is, is just a pointer to a commit, and since graphql is strongly typed (and refs can be different things) we need to let it know it is a commit,

```
   target{
      ...on Commit {

      }
   }
```

so target is what our ref is pointing to, and we say "if its a commit, do this"

and what should it do? 
it should get the most recent commit (since that will have the latest files in the repo)

so to do that we query history

```
        history(first: 1 until: "2019-10-08T00:00:00"){
            nodes{

            }
        }
```

now inside of `nodes` we are inside of our commit and now we can see the files,
the files in a commits pointer are really just a pointer to a tree, and a tree just has entries, which can be objects of either type Tree, or type blob

entries that represent files are known as blobs, but since we dont do anything with them but list their names, you dont even need to know that

but its important to know that trees are also entries, so if you find a tree you need to dig in deeper, but you can only go a pre defined amount of levels deep.

```
       tree{
           entries {
             name
             object {
               ...on Tree{
                 entries{
                   name
                   object {
                      ...on Tree{
                        entries{
                          name
                        }
                      }
                   }
                 }
               }
             }
           } 
       }
```

now to put it all together:

```
query{
  repository(owner: "MyLogin", name: "MyRepo") {
    defaultBranchRef {
      target {
        ... on Commit {
          history(first: 1 until: "2019-10-08T00:00:00") {
            nodes {
              tree {
                entries {
                  name
                  object {
                    ... on Tree {
                      entries {
                        name
                        object{
                          ...on Tree{
                            entries{
                              name
                              object{
                                ...on Tree{
                                  entries{
                                    name
                                  }                                  
                                }
                              }
                            }   
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

As Dan mentioned: [github trees](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/)

See working example below

```py
import requests

user = "grumbach"
repo = "ft_ping"

url = "https://api.github.com/repos/{}/{}/git/trees/master?recursive=1".format(user, repo)
r = requests.get(url)
res = r.json()

for file in res["tree"]:
    print(file["path"])
```

> For the sake of simplicity I omitted error management, velociraptors are extinct anyway…

Comment: sometimes you just need a simple answer to save the day. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

##### Use [`gh api`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_api) for authenticated HTTP request to the GitHub API

###### in one line

```
gh api -X GET /repos/octocat/Hello-World/commits | grep -E -o ".{0,0}\[{\"sha\":\".{0,40}" | sed 's/\[{\"sha\":\"//' | xargs -I {} gh api -X GET /repos/octocat/Hello-World/commits/{} | grep -E -o "\"filename\":\".*?\""
```

---

###### Or in two steps

###### Get commits sha

```sh
gh api -X GET /repos/octocat/Hello-World/commits | grep -E -o ".{0,0}\[{\"sha\":\".{0,40}" | sed 's/\[{\"sha\":\"//' >> ~/commits
```

###### List file names

```sh
xargs < ~/commits -I {} gh api -X GET /repos/octocat/Hello-World/commits/{} | grep -E -o "\"filename\":\".*?\""
```

Answer (score 0):

Examples of two REST API that use JavaScript to get a list of all the files in a repository:

```
const { Octokit, App } = await import("https://esm.sh/octokit");

const octokit = new Octokit({ auth: `...` });
```

---

1

```
var res = await octokit.request('GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/contents/{path}', {
    owner: 'aaa',
    repo: 'bbb',
    path: '',
    headers: {
        'X-GitHub-Api-Version': '2022-11-28'
    }
})
```

2

```
var res2 = await octokit.request('GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/git/trees/{tree_sha}?recursive=1', {
    owner: 'aaa',
    repo: 'bbb',
    tree_sha: 'main',
    headers: {
        'X-GitHub-Api-Version': '2022-11-28'
    }
})
```

The structure of the resulting response object:

```
{
    "data": ...,
    "headers": ...,
    "status": ...,
    "url": ...,
}
```

The difference between the two API is that **contents** API can only get all the files in the first layer. For directories, only the following form can be obtained.

```
{
    "name": "qqq",
    "path": "qqq",
    "sha": "67dde9a49bc1544ca852b2f14bde5f661c9d9f6d",
    "size": 0,
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/.../contents/qqq?ref=main",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/.../tree/main/qqq",
    "git_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/.../git/trees/67dde9a49bc1544ca852b2f14bde5f661c9d9f6d",
    "download_url": null,
    **"type": "dir",**
    "_links": {
        "self": "...",
        "git": "...",
        "html": "..."
    }
}
```

And the **trees** API can retrieve subdirectories recursively through the addition of the recursive= parameter.

```
{
    "path": "111/222/333.js",
    "mode": "100644",
    "type": "blob",
    "sha": "d70ba342e2cccf511a8397133c2ba33d24e6e370",
    "size": 27353,
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/.../git/blobs/d70ba342e2cccf511a8397133c2ba33d24e6e370"
}
```