# How to get list files from a github repository folder using R

Tags: r, github

I am wondering if there exists a function or a link or any method that would work like `list.files()` function in R but on a folder stored on a github repostiory.

example github repository folder: https://github.com/KZPS/Spotkania/tree/master/Matteo/literature

Thanks for any advice !

Comment: You could always execute a system call, e.g. `system('git ls-tree --full-tree -r HEAD')`  . See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533202/list-files-in-local-git-repo for possibly useful info

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
library(httr)
req <- GET("https://api.github.com/repos/KZPS/Spotkania/git/trees/master?recursive=1")
stop_for_status(req)
filelist <- unlist(lapply(content(req)$tree, "[", "path"), use.names = F)
grep("Matteo/literature/", filelist, value = TRUE, fixed = TRUE)
# [1] "Matteo/literature/Subsetting.pdf"     
# [2] "Matteo/literature/datatable-intro.pdf"
```

You could easily build a function `list.files.github` from that.

Comment: To fetch just one folder you can also use the following URL: https://api.github.com/repos/KZPS/Spotkania/contents/Matteo/literature

Comment: using `r-lib/gh` that wrap the api.github.com you can use `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/git/trees/:tree_sha?recursive=1` see https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/#get-a-tree-recursively

Comment: Just in case, to build the URL: https://api.github.com/repos/[USER]/[REPO]/git/trees/[BRANCH]?recursive=1  
FROM: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61656698/1873521

Answer (score -1):

I forked the repo then cloned the fork on my local directory. I made the forked the directory my working directory and was able to use list.files()

Comment: This means you download repository to know what files are in it. But I wanted only to know what files are on github to download only specific files. Not a good idea of you

Comment: @MarcinKosinski Your assessment is fair enough. I'm sure there are much better ways.