# How to specify user agent when using github API?

Tags: r, httr

I want to obtain the list of files on a Github repo. I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25485782/11598948) but I noticed that sometimes I have a HTTP 403 error. For example, if I run the following code:

```
library(httr)

for (i in 1:10) {
  req <- GET("https://api.github.com/repos/etiennebacher/tidytuesday/git/trees/master?recursive=1")
  stop_for_status(req)
}

> Error: Forbidden (HTTP 403).
```

(Note that I don't actually want to run this GET request 10 times, it's just the easiest way I found to simulate my problem. )

Searching a bit online, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39912696/11598948) that explains that the Github API requires the GitHub username, or the name of the application, for the `User-Agent` header value of the request.

But adding `user_agent("etiennebacher")` in `GET()` doesn't change anything. How should I specify the user agent in this case?

Also asked on [RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-specify-user-agent-when-using-github-api/113487)

Comment: Maybe the user-agent is something else: https://rdrr.io/cran/httr/man/user_agent.html . I seem to remember the agent being the name of softwares. E.g. Mozilla or chrome.

Comment: Not necessarily, e.g `GET(url = "http://httpbin.org/user-agent")` gives `"user-agent": "libcurl/7.64.1 r-curl/4.3.2 httr/1.4.2"`. But we can also customize them, e.g `GET(url = "http://httpbin.org/user-agent", user_agent("hello"))` gives `"user-agent": "hello"`. But for some reason I can't make the github api works with that

Comment: I don’t know the answer but I would have tried that libcurl specification or one of the other two.

Comment: Is the error you are getting only "Forbidden"? Or does it actually return a specific message about the "user agent". The GET request does send a default user agent and the `httr::user_agent()` function does change that when included in the `GET("http:///", user_agent("whatever"))`. Have you done any form of authentication? Unauthenticated request are limited to a few requests per hour.

Comment: @MrFlick Indeed the message is `API rate limit exceeded...`, which could be solved by authenticating. I also found the package `gh` that makes it a bit easier to authenticate (via `gh::gh_whoami()`). That solves it locally, but I don't know how to authenticate in Github actions (which is where the code above is supposed to run). I read [this page](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/authentication-in-a-workflow) but I don't know how to pass `GITHUB_TOKEN` as an input in an R function yet. I'll open another question for that if I can't find a way.

Comment: Well your question didn't mention a GitHub actions context so that wasn't clear. But basically basically yeah, you need to use the secrets stuff. There's an example at the bottom of the [encrypting secrets page](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets) that shows how you can pass values as environment variables to your step. Then you can use `Sys.getenv()` in your R script to access that environment variable.

Comment: Yes I know I forgot to mention it in the post. I'm gonna write an answer for the original question based on your comments, and then add the github actions part as a "bonus" as soon as I found how to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by @MrFlick, the HTTP 403 here means that the API rate limit was exceeded. A way to solve this is to authenticate when making the request, because the rate limit goes [from 60 to 5,000 requests per hour](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api#rate-limiting). It is easier to do so by using the package `gh` (and its eponymous function). This can be done locally by specifying `.token = <PAT>` (where `<PAT>` is your GitHub Personal Access Token) in `gh()`.

To obtain the list of files in a particular repo, you can save the output of `gh()` in a JSON file, and then read it with `jsonlite::fromJSON()`. It is then trivial to get the list of files.

Bottom line, this works:

```
library(gh)
library(jsonlite)

tmp_file <- tempfile(fileext = ".json")

gh::gh("https://api.github.com/repos/etiennebacher/tidytuesday/git/trees/master?recursive=1", .destfile = tmp_file, .token = <PAT>)

jsonlite::fromJSON(tmp_file)$tree$path
```

**Bonus: how to authenticate in Github Actions**

I didn't say it in the original post, but this GET request was supposed to be made in a Github action. Since you can't manually provide the PAT as a token, you need to define the token in the `.yaml` file, and then pass its value in the `.R` file.

`test.R`

```
library(gh)
library(jsonlite)

tmp_file <- tempfile(fileext = ".json")

gh::gh("https://api.github.com/repos/etiennebacher/tidytuesday/git/trees/master?recursive=1", .destfile = tmp_file, .token = github_token)

jsonlite::fromJSON(tmp_file)$tree$path
```

GitHub action:

```
on:
  push:
    branches: master

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: macOS-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r@master
      - run: |
          github_token <- "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
          install.packages(c("gh", "jsonlite"))
          source("test.R"),
        shell: Rscript {0}
```