# Python get list of csv files in public GitHub repository

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycurl, pygithub

I am trying to pull some csv files from a [public repository](https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/tree/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports) using Python. I have the code to process the data after I have the files' URL. Is there some sort of equivalent to `ls` for GitHub? I'm not seeing anything in GitHub's API, also it seems like it's possible using PyCurl, but then I'll need to parse through the html. Is there any prebuilt way to do this?

Comment: Git trees API? https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all file names from a Github repo through the Github API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25022016/get-all-file-names-from-a-github-repo-through-the-github-api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BeautifulSoup (hacky and probably very inefficient) solution:

```
# Import the required packages: 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import re 

# Store the url as a string scalar: url => str
url = "https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/tree/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports"

# Issue request: r => requests.models.Response
r = requests.get(url)

# Extract text: html_doc => str
html_doc = r.text

# Parse the HTML: soup => bs4.BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)

# Find all 'a' tags (which define hyperlinks): a_tags => bs4.element.ResultSet
a_tags = soup.find_all('a')

# Store a list of urls ending in .csv: urls => list
urls = ['https://raw.githubusercontent.com'+re.sub('/blob', '', link.get('href')) 
        for link in a_tags  if '.csv' in link.get('href')]

# Store a list of Data Frame names to be assigned to the list: df_list_names => list
df_list_names = [url.split('.csv')[0].split('/')[url.count('/')] for url in urls]

# Initialise an empty list the same length as the urls list: df_list => list
df_list = [pd.DataFrame([None]) for i in range(len(urls))]

# Store an empty list of dataframes: df_list => list
df_list = [pd.read_csv(url, sep = ',') for url in urls]

# Name the dataframes in the list, coerce to a dictionary: df_dict => dict
df_dict = dict(zip(df_list_names, df_list))
```