# How to list files from enterprise GitHub repository without cloning

Tags: github-api, enterprise

I am trying to list the files present on an enterprise GitHub repository. I tried using GitHub API but base URL for it is
`api.github.com` where as base URL would be different for me and when I put that URL it says couldn't resolve. How can I achieve it for a URL in below format
`https://company.net/org/reponame`

Below example works for me but the URL that I have it doesn't work
 `curl -k https://api.github.com/user/repo?refs=master`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an on-premise GitHub Enterprise, the [documentation mentions](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@2.21/rest/reference/enterprise-admin)

> REST API endpoints — except Management Console API endpoints — are prefixed with the following URL:

```
http(s)://[hostname]/api/v3
```

In your case: https://company.net/api/v3

From there, using the [Git Database API -- list tree](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/git#trees), you can list all files, as [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62003257/6309).