# List files in repo using `gh` from GitHub CLI?

Tags: git, github-cli

Is there a `gh` command to list files in a directory without having a working copy clone?

I have found a git command that will do it, but I think this is working only on the local working copy.

```
git ls-tree --name-only HEAD
git ls-tree --name-only -r HEAD
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25022016/get-all-file-names-from-a-github-repo-through-the-github-api maybe with the `gh api` command?

Comment: @erik258, yes, that is the question. Is there a `gh` command? The link you provided is good, but I am unable to formulate a pattern for accessing a GitHub hosted Enterprise account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gh api` is a `gh` command that can help you call [the github apis](https://docs.github.com/en/rest?apiVersion=2022-11-28).  You can use the `-q` option to use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to sort

For example, here's one way to get a list of contents in one command, based on the [`trees` api](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/git/trees?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-a-tree):

```
gh api '/repos/{owner}/{repo}/git/trees/{branch}?recursive=true' -q '.tree[]|.path'
```

Here, `owner` is your github user (or organization) name, `repo` is the repo name, `branch` is the branch name.  Then `.tree[]|.path` turns the raw json output into a list of just paths in your repo.

`recursive` option will save you from having to recurse the directory structure yourself, but [has a size limit](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/git/trees?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-a-tree)

> Note: The limit for the tree array is 100,000 entries with a maximum size of 7 MB when using the recursive parameter.

If you're concerned about that limit, you'll have to do your own recursion.

There is also a [`contents` api](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents?apiVersion=2022-11-28) (with the same 100k limit) as well as [one for tarballs or zipfiles](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents?apiVersion=2022-11-28#download-a-repository-archive-tar) if you're interested in the contents of those files and not just their names.

I encourage you to explore [the github apis](https://docs.github.com/en/rest?apiVersion=2022-11-28) in depth - github has some really interesting APIs and did a very good job implementing them.