# How to get the download link of all files in a repo?

Tags: github, github-api, git-api

With the following command, I'm able to get `download_url` for the files on my GitHub repo, but it doesn't include files that are inside folders:

```
curl -H "Authorization: token ghp_..." -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw" -L "https://api.github.com/repos/<USER>/<REPO>/contents"
```

While searching around I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61656698/10993384), the following command lists all files recursively, but it doesn't include the `download_url`:

```
curl -H "Authorization: token ghp_..." -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw" -L "https://api.github.com/repos/<USER>/<REPO>/git/trees/main?recursive=1"
```

How i could get the `download_url` of **ALL** files in the repo?

Answer (score 0):

Construct the download_url using the "`path`" member of the objects returned from the `/repos/{owner}/{repo}/git/trees/{tree_sha}` endpoint.

The template appears to be `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/{owner}/{repo}/{branch/commit-sha/tree-sha}/{path}`